# Flutter switch rotated but only visually

Tags: flutter, rotation, switch-statement, widget

I got a Cupertino Switch in my Flutter app.
I wanted to use this Switch Widget vertically.

When I use "Transform.rotate()" It rotates but when it comes to work;
It logically stayes the same layout, horizontally.

So rotation just works visually. Is there any way to change the logical orientation of any flutter object?

```dart
child: Transform.rotate(
              angle: -3.14 / 2, // -90 degree, vertical
              child: new CupertinoSwitch(
                value: activity,
                onChanged: (bool value) {
                  setState(() {
                    ...
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: could you explain the issue? It's working fine here

Comment: Widget working, the issue is; visual and logical orientation of the switch is not same. I think the gesture listener of switch stays the same while It visually rotating.

It continues to listen left to right movement, not bottom to up.

Answer (score 1):

A **RotatedBox()** widget should do the trick.